# Get Spark dataset metadata

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to convert the `Dataset<row>` into another object. Possibly be `java.list`. And I need to extract the metadata for this dataset. Like the number of column, column names and column types. Is there anyway to do it?
Thank you

Comment: Have you tried exploring the Dataset API documentation (https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html)?

Answer (score 3):

You can get the schema from dataset as

```
ds.schema
```

This gives you StructType which contains all the information

```
ds.schema.fieldNames
```

This gives all the list of column names

```
ds.schema.fields
```

This gives you a list of `StructField` which contains `column name`, `datatype` and `nullable` as a `boolean` value.

```
ds.schema.size
```

This gives the total count of column names

Also, you can see the details with `ds.printSchema()`

Hope this helps!

Comment: I hope this helped

Comment: If I want some other other metadata like total number of rows, dataset size (bytes), number of non-null values for a column?